# put vectors inside a vector

Tags: vector

I have an empty vector like U = {}.
In an iteration, I get u1 = {a, b} and I want to put the vector in U to have {{},{a,b}}. I can do this simply with U = {U, u1} command.
But in another iteration, I get for example u2={c} and want to have {{},{a,b},{c}}. How can I do this?

If I use the same command as before: U = {U, u2} I will have {{{},{a,b}},{c}} but I want to have only {{},{a,b},{c}}

Thanks All

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe use Append. But there are functions like NestList and FoldList that might give you what you want "for free". Would need to see more details of what you're doing.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I don't think I understand the question. Does u have a specific structure?

Comment: That's not enough information. At the very least, put a minimal example of the structure of your nested loops into your question (not in a comment).

Comment: Since you already have `s` and presumably `lp` is defined, you could do this: `FoldList[Append[#1, s[#2]] &, {}, Range[lp]]`

Comment: The questions should demonstrate some effort and it would be best if you could show us what you have already tried. Please edit your question to update accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

This code does what I think you want based on your question

```
ClearAll[append];
(* define modified Append function *)
append[{}, ui_] := {{}, ui};
append[u_, ui_] := Append[u, ui];
U = {}; u1 = {a,b}; u2 = {c};
U = append[U, u1]
(* {{}, {a, b}} *)
U = append[U, u2]
(* {{}, {a, b}, {c}} *)
```